# Counting Duplicate Row in internal table

Tags: abap

I need to count the number of duplicate rows in an internal table base on one field.

I have tried to create a work area and counting the duplicate data but the problem is it counts all duplicate data. My purpose is to count duplicate data by the same date.

```
DATA: gv_line TYPE i.

gv_line = 0.
LOOP AT i_sect_proe.
  IF wa_sect_proe IS INITIAL.
     wa_sect_proe = i_sect_proe.
     CONTINUE.
  ENDIF.

  IF wa_sect_proe-/smr/wondat EQ i_final_f-/smr/wondat.
     gv_line = gv_line + 1.
  ENDIF.

  i_sect_proe-/smr/line = gv_line.
ENDLOOP.
```

The code I've tried displays the number off all duplicate data.

Comment: Post a full working example, please.

Comment: The full version of my working was too long, i cant post here because its load the characters can be display.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show duplicates in internal table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165679/show-duplicates-in-internal-table)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - You have to spend a little time to write it so that the question is made clear. Your example code needs to include only two columns, an internal table initialized with three lines, then show the current result, what you expect, what you tried...

Answer (score -2):

DATA: BEGIN OF lt_result OCCURS 0,
               date TYPE datum,
               count TYPE i,
           END OF lt_result.

SORT yourTable BY dateField.

LOOP AT yourTable.
    lt_result-date   = yourTable-dateField.
    lt_result-count = 1.
    COLLECT lt_result INTO lt_result.
ENDLOOP.

Result in lt_result[].